# How does linux handle overflow in jiffies?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, overflow

Suppose we have a following code:

```
if (timeout > jiffies)
{
    /* we did not time out, good ... */
}
else
{
    /* we timed out, error ...*
}
```

This code works fine when jiffies value do not overflow.
However, when jiffies overflow and wrap around to zero, this code doesn't work properly.

Linux apparently provides macros for dealing with this overflow problem

```
#define time_before(unknown, known) ((long)(unkown) - (long)(known) < 0)
```

and code above is supposed to be safe against overflow when replaced with this macro:

```
// SAFE AGAINST OVERFLOW
if (time_before(jiffies, timeout)
{
    /* we did not time out, good ... */
}
else
{
    /* we timed out, error ...*
}
```

But, what is the rationale behind time_before (and other time_ macros?

time_before(jiffies, timeout) will be expanded to

```
((long)(jiffies) - (long)(timeout) < 0)
```

How does this code prevent overflow problems?

Comment: why do you set `timeout = 10;` and not an `timeout = -2147483000;` which is better test for overflow? Note, that usually signed type is overflowed to negative, not to positive.

Comment: I am trying to get how "time_before" macro is robust against overflow. Apparently, it doesn't handle the case where two unsigned long values are nowhere close to overflow.

Comment: Yes, because this case is ambiguous. You as human can say that 10>2147483647; but computer can't think like a user. It thinks, that when comparing jiffles, there is more likely that there was no overflow in past 24 days (HZ=1000) or 248 days (HZ=100).

Comment: Well, aren't time_after, time_before macros designed to deal with jiffie overflows? If there is still problem with jiffies overflow, then what is the point of coming up with those "safe" macros?

Comment: I think, there is a problem in your test and your misunderstanding of how to use time_before and time_after. Please, update the page and read my answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry I was misunderstanding the concept of timeout (which is supposed to be old_jiffies+some HZ). I will probably post another question about underlying rationale behind those macros. Thank you very much for taking time to clear up my question.

Comment: this macro are ok for short time and wrong for several-days timeout (for very high HZ) or even for 24 or 48 of 72 days; so they should be used only in places, where timeout is rather small.

Answer (score 12):

Let's actually give it a try:

```
#define time_before(unknown, known) ((long)(unkown) - (long)(known) < 0)
```

I'll simplify things down a lot by saying that a `long` is only two bytes, so in hex it can have a value in the range `[0, 0xFFFF]`.

Now, it's signed, so the range [0, 0xFFFF] can be broken into two separate ranges [0, 0x7FFF], [0x8000, 0xFFFF]. Those correspond to the values [0, 32767], [ -32768, -1]. Here's a diagram:

```
[0x0      -              -                  -               0xFFFF]
[0x0                       0x7FFF][0x8000                   0xFFFF]
[0                         32,767][-32,768                      -1]
```

Say `timeout` is 32,000. We want to check if we're inside our timeout, but in truth we overflowed, so `jiffies` is -31,000. So if we naively tried to evaluate `jiffies < timeout` we'd get `True`. But, plugging in the values:

```
   time_before(jiffies, offset)
== ((long)(jiffies) - (long)(offset) < 0)
== (-31000 - 32000 < 0)             // WTF is this. Clearly NOT -63000
== (-31000 - 1768 - 1 - 30231 < 0)  // simply expanded 32000
== (-32768 - 1 - 30232 < 0)         // this -1 causes an underflow
== (32767 - 30232 < 0)
== (2535 < 0)
== False
```

`jiffies` are 4 bytes, not 2, but the same principle applies. Does that help at all?

Comment: I actually don't think this case is the reason for time_before macro. As you can see, for this case, we don't need to use time_before macro, since raw comparison (timeout = 32000, but jiffy will be 34536, since 34536 is in the range of unsigned long) gives the same (yet much simpler) answer. The problem lies when jiffy overflows unsigned range, and wraps around to become a zero. But thanks for coming out with a very specific example.

Comment: As I said in my post, (at the beginning) "I'll simplify things down a lot by saying that a long is only two bytes". Then at the end, "jiffies are 4 bytes, not 2, but the same principle applies"

Comment: If I wrote it out with longs, all the 0xFFFF would be 0xFFFFFFFF which I think would be hard to read

Answer (score 4):

See for example here: http://fixunix.com/kernel/266713-%5Bpatch-1-4%5D-fs-autofs-use-time_before-time_before_eq-etc.html

Code with checking overflow against some fixed small constant was converted to use time_before. Why?

> I'm just summarizing the comment that goes with the definition of the
>   time_after etc functions:
>
> [include/linux/jiffies.h:93](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/linux/jiffies.h#L93)

```
 93 /*
 94  *      These inlines deal with timer wrapping correctly. You are 
 95  *      strongly encouraged to use them
 96  *      1. Because people otherwise forget
 97  *      2. Because if the timer wrap changes in future you won't have to
 98  *         alter your driver code.
 99  *
100  * time_after(a,b) returns true if the time a is after time b.
101  *
```

So, `time_before` and `time_after` is the better effort of handling overflow.

Your testcase is more likely to be `timeout < jiffles` (w/o overflow) than `timeout > jiffles` (with overflow):

```
unsigned long jiffies = 2147483658;
unsigned long timeout = 10;
```

And if you will change timeout to

```
unsigned long timeout = -2146483000;
```

what will be an answer?

Or you can change the check from

```
printf("%d",time_before(jiffies,timeout));
```

to

```
printf("%d",time_before(jiffies,old_jiffles+timeout));
```

where old_jiffles is saved value of jiffles at the timer's start.

So, I think the usage of time_before can be like:

```
old_jiffles=jiffles;
timeout=10;  // or even 10*HZ for ten-seconds

do_a_long_work_or_wait();

//check is the timeout reached or not
if(time_before(jiffies,old_jiffles+timeout) ) {
  do_another_long_work_or_wait();
} else {
  printk("ERRROR: the timeout is reached; here is a problem");
  panic();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `jiffies` is an unsigned value, a simple comparison is safe across one wraparound point (where signed values would jump from positive to negative) but not safe across the other point (where signed values would jump from negative to positive, and where unsigned values jump from high to low).  It's protection against this second point that the macro is intended to solve.

**There is a fundamental assumption that `timeout` was initially calculated as `jiffies + some_offset` at some prior *recent* point in time -- specifically, less than half the range of the variables.  If you're trying to measure times longer than this then things break down and you'll get the wrong answer.**

If we pretend that `jiffies` is 16-bit wide for convenience in the explanation (similar to the other answers):

### `timeout > jiffies`

This is an unsigned comparison that is intended to return true if we have not yet reached the timeout.  Some examples:

- `timeout == 0x0300, jiffies == 0x0100`: result is true, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x8100, jiffies == 0x7F00`: result is true, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x0100, jiffies == 0xFF00`: oops, result is false, but we haven't *really* reached the timeout, it just wrapped the counter.
- `timeout == 0x0100, jiffies == 0x0300`: result is false, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x7F00, jiffies == 0x8100`: result is false, as expected.
- `timeout == 0xFF00, jiffies == 0x0100`: oops, result is true, but we did pass the timeout.

### time_before(jiffies, timeout)

This does a signed comparison on the *difference* of the values rather than the values themselves, and again is expected to return true if the timeout has not yet been reached.  Provided that the assumption above is upheld, the same examples:

- `timeout == 0x0300, jiffies == 0x0100`: result is true, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x8100, jiffies == 0x7F00`: result is true, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x0100, jiffies == 0xFF00`: result is true, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x0100, jiffies == 0x0300`: result is false, as expected.
- `timeout == 0x7F00, jiffies == 0x8100`: result is false, as expected.
- `timeout == 0xFF00, jiffies == 0x0100`: result is false, as expected.

If the offset you used when calculating `timeout` is too large or you allow too much time to pass after calculating `timeout`, then the result can still be wrong.  eg. if you calculate `timeout` once but then just keep testing it repeatedly, then `time_before` will initially be true, then change to false after the offset time has passed -- and then change back to true again after 0x8000 time has passed (however long that is; it depends on the tick rate).  This is why when you reach the timeout, you're supposed to remember this and stop checking the time (or recalculate a new timeout).

In the real kernel, `jiffies` is longer than 16 bits so it will take longer for it to wrap, but it's still possible if the machine is run for long enough.  (And typically it's set to wrap shortly after boot, to catch these bugs more quickly.)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't easily understand the above answers, so hoping to help with my own:

#define time_after(a,b) (long) ( (b) - (a) )

Here brackets around 'b' and 'a' make them signed.

Example overflow:

For convenience, imagine 8-bit integers, jiffy1 is changing and timeout is fixed and greater than jiffy1

like : jiffy1 = 252, timeout = 254 and jiffy2 becomes 0 or 1 after overflow

**When we use unsigned:**

jiffy1 < timeout and

jiffy2 < timeout (mistakenly due to overflow which we need to fix via MACRO)

**When we use signed:**

jiffy1 < timeout (more-negative < less-negative)

and

jiffy2 > timeout (positive > negative)

(because it will consider MSB as the sign bit, hence timeout will appear negative while our jiffy2 has become positive due to the overflow)

Do correct me if there is something wrong